# Как добавить данные в бд Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных, entity-framework

Хочу создать приложение WPF, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не понимаю как добавлять данные из textBox в бд. Я cоздал модель с помощью Code First, и пытался записать данные с textBox в бд. Использовал этот код.
Может кто сможет помочь?

```
string Name = this.name.Text;
db.managment.Add(new managment(Name));
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Вам поможет любая документация по EF, где расскажут и как подключиться к базе, и как создать модели, и как работать. А сейчас, ну вот что вы от нас хотите, чтоб мы расписывали подробно как это все делать? Ну ок: `db.MySuperTable.Add(new MySuperClass("...")); db.SaveChanges();`.

Comment: Прошу прощения что не написал сразу, но я создал модель с помощью Code First, и пытался записать в бд тем же способом что написали и вы, только беру я данные с textBox.

Comment: и...? Почему вот я из вас должен все вытягивать то? Вот представьте, что вы вышли на улицу и первому встречному сказали "Слушайте, а как добавить в базу данные?". Вот встаньте на место этого человека, он сможет дать вам ответ, не зная всех деталей вашего проекта, что делаете, что получаете, и так далее? Нет конечно, даже если он будет супер профи своего дела, без данных он вас скорей всего вежливо пошлет) А все почему? А потому, что это вы обязаны предоставить все необходимое сразу, прям разжевать свой вопрос до мельчайших деталей, чтоб понял каждый, тогда да, получите ответ. А сейчас...